# Generate a TIN or DEM with soft breaklines in qgis, postgis or grass

Tags: qgis, postgis, grass-gis

I have 3 datasets to use as input for a digital elevation model

- contours (3d line)
- points (3d point)
- breakline (2d line, in blue)

[image: soft breaklines for DEM generation]

The third input, the `breakline` do not have an elevation value or zvalue. They are soft breaklines. [ESRI quick description on hard vs soft breaklines](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/breaklines-in-surface-modeling.htm)

I tried using QGIS `TIN Interpolation` tool but it only allows hard breaklines.

I seen from PostGIS that there is a [Constrained Delaunay Triangulation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConstrainedDelaunayTriangles.html) tool but not sure how to input the three layers into it to get a DEM.

Lastly I got the result in a TIN from [GRASS using v.triangle](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/TIN_with_breaklines) - an old commercial license plugin - but cannot figure out how to convert that TIN to raster from within GRASS. The resulting TIN does not show up as a valid input for conversion tools.

Comment: In my opinion, if the nodes of the lines have no elevation, the lines can't be included in any interpolation. Triangulation would not be a problem as long as you do not intend to assign a third dimension to the vertices of the generated triangles.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca theres a difference between soft breaklines (don't have a z value) but influence the edge they represent. they aren't hard breaklines that have a z value to use. these soft breaklines represent rivers, creeks, lakes, etc so are needed in the interpolation

Comment: When you create a TIN in ArcGIS you can specify whether in input lines are hard or soft break lines and whether their z values contribute to the TIN.  You can included a boundary polygon with similar arguments.  After the TIN is created you can export the TIN to a raster file type of your choice.  If you are running Windows, consider a 21 Day free trial.

Comment: @GBG thanks, but I haven't touched arc in years and really don't have the option to. it doesn't run on Linux natively. it is how I did it in the past but GRASS GIS v.triangle tool is the next best thing! can't figure out how to do any analysis on the resulting tin in grass though

Comment: Have you tried the BaseMesh QGIS plugin?https://git.ee.ethz.ch/BASEMENTpublic/basemesh-v2/-/wikis/plugin/user-manual-for-v2.0 It also uses Shewchuk's Triangle mesh generator like the GRASS v.triangle plugin. Once you are satisfied with your mesh, you can export it to 2DM mesh format and then use the QGIS "Rasterize mesh dataset" processing tool to convert the 2DM to a raster.

Comment: @BrentEdwards thanks! I am having a look and will update my question with results. Looks promising!!!

Comment: One more option is to use GMT https://docs.generic-mapping-tools.org/dev/surface.html but it seems to require z-values for the soft breakline.